# GXT Fieldset Checkbox toggle

Tags: gxt

I am using sencha gxt 3.x, the Fieldset comes with default toggleButton, instead of button I want to display checkbox.

The older version of gxt 2.x has fieldSet.setCheckboxToggle(true) which was removed in 3.x, is there a workaround solution to toggle fieldset with checkbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CheckedFieldSet extends FieldSet {

HBoxLayoutContainer bar = new HBoxLayoutContainer();
CheckBox state = new CheckBox();

@Override
protected void onAfterFirstAttach() {
    super.onAfterFirstAttach();
    bar.add(getCollapseButton());
    bar.add(state);
    if (isCollapsible()) {
        state.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                if (state.getValue()) {
                    ComponentHelper.doAttach(asWidget());
                } else {
                    ComponentHelper.doDetach(asWidget());
                }
            }
        });
        ComponentHelper.doAttach(state);
        getAppearance().getToolElement(getElement()).appendChild(bar.getElement());
    }
}

public HandlerRegistration addChangeHandler(ChangeHandler handler){
    return state.addChangeHandler(handler);
}

public void setActive(boolean state){
    this.state.setValue(state, true, true);
}
}
```